# Why is an asyncio task garbage collected when opening a connection inside it?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am creating a server which needs to make an external request while responding. To handle concurrent requests I'm using Python's `asyncio` library. I have followed [some examples from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams). It seems however that some of my tasks are destroyed, printing `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` to my terminal. After some debugging and research I found [a stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304603/python-asyncio-unreferenced-tasks-are-destroyed-by-garbage-collector) which seemed to explain why.

I have created a minimal example demonstrating this effect below. **My question** is in what way should one counteract this effect? Storing a hard reference to the task, by for example storing `asyncio.current_task()` in a global variable mitigates the issue. It also seems to work fine if I wrap the future `remote_read.read()` as `await asyncio.wait_for(remote_read.read(), 5)`. However I do feel like these solutions are ugly.

```py
# run and visit http://localhost:8080/ in your browser
import asyncio
import gc

async def client_connected_cb(reader, writer):
    remote_read, remote_write = await asyncio.open_connection("google.com", 443, ssl=True)
    await remote_read.read()

async def cleanup():
    while True:
        gc.collect()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_connected_cb, "localhost", 8080)
    await asyncio.gather(server.serve_forever(), cleanup())

asyncio.run(main())
```

I am running Python 3.10 on macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: This is a bug in CPython. I presume you're the one who sent a [patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30505).

I've reviewed the patch and requested some changes.

Comment: Related to [Python 3.10 asyncio server task gets destroyed when reading from reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059327/python-3-10-asyncio-server-task-gets-destroyed-when-reading-from-reader)

Answer (score 2):

It looks that by the time being, the only way is actually keeping
a reference manually.

Maybe a decorator is something more convenient than having
to manually add the code in each async function.
I opted for the class design, so that a class attribute
can hold the hard-references while the tasks run. (A
local variable in the wrapper function would be part
of the task-reference cycle, and the garbage collection
would trigger all the same):

```
# run and visit http://localhost:8080/ in your browser
import asyncio
import gc
from functools import wraps
import weakref

class Shielded:
    registry = set()

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    async def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.registry.add(task:=asyncio.current_task())
        try:
            result = await self.func(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            self.registry.remove(task)
        return result

def _Shielded(func):
    # Used along with the print sequence to assert the task was actually destroyed without commenting
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ref = weakref.finalize(asyncio.current_task(), lambda: print("task destroyed"))
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@Shielded
async def client_connected_cb(reader, writer):
    print("at task start")
    #registry.append(asyncio.current_task())
    # I've connected this to a socket in an interactive session, I'd explictly .close() for debugging:
    remote_read, remote_write = await asyncio.open_connection("localhost", 8060, ssl=False)
    print("comensing remote read")
    await remote_read.read()
    print("task complete")

async def cleanup():
    while True:
        gc.collect()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_connected_cb, "localhost", 8080)
    await asyncio.gather(server.serve_forever(), cleanup())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Moreover, I wanted to "really see it", so I created a "fake" `_Shielded`
decorator that would just log something when the underlying task
got deleted: "task complete" is never printed with it, indeed.