# Python 3.10 asyncio server task gets destroyed when reading from reader

Tags: python, server, python-asyncio, p2p

I'm trying to write a peer to peer node in asyncio. In order to answer one type of request the node can forward the request to another node. My problem is that when node A forwards to node B and node B forwards back to A, the task answering the request sometimes gets cancelled giving a "Task was destroyed but it was pending!".

This happens when reading from the reader provided by running the server created by asyncio.start_server.

Here is some code that reproduces the issue:

```
import sys
import asyncio

global neighbor
neighbor = None

async def make_request(host, port, n):
    task = asyncio.current_task()
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
    print(f"Making request to {(host, port)}")

    writer.write(n.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
    await writer.drain()

    task.set_name(task.get_name()+"_here")
    #
    ###
    ##### FAILS HERE
    ###
    #
    resp_len = await reader.read(1)
    task.set_name(task.get_name()+"_not_here")
    resp_len = int.from_bytes(resp_len, 'big')
    resp = await reader.read(resp_len)
    print(f"Response from {(host, port)}: {resp}")

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    return resp_len, resp


async def handle_request(reader, writer):
    print(f'Got request from {writer.get_extra_info("peername")}')
    n = int.from_bytes(await reader.read(4), 'big')
    if n == 0:
        writer.write(b'\x04\x01\x02\x03\x04')
        await writer.drain()
    else:
        resp_len, resp = await make_request(*neighbor, n-1)
        writer.write(resp_len.to_bytes(1, 'big') + resp)
        await writer.drain()
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=0):
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_request, host, port)
    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f"Serving on {addrs}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__=="__main__":
    if sys.argv[1] == 'node1':
        neighbor = ('127.0.0.1', 7776)
        asyncio.run(run_server(port=8889))
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'node2':
        neighbor = ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
        asyncio.run(run_server(port=7776))
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'client':
        for i in range(10000):
            asyncio.run(make_request('127.0.0.1', 7776, n=2))
```

Running in 3 terminals with the arguments "node1", "node2" and "client" respectively, the ouput of node2 is:

```
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 7776)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46620)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46630)
Response from ('127.0.0.1', 8889): b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46646)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46652)
Response from ('127.0.0.1', 8889): b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46656)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46670)
Response from ('127.0.0.1', 8889): b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46678)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46686)
Response from ('127.0.0.1', 8889): b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46700)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46706)
Response from ('127.0.0.1', 8889): b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46722)
Making request to ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-24_here' coro=<handle_request() done, defined at /home/colm/Documents/Exodus/node_test.py:32> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Got request from ('127.0.0.1', 46734)
```

While node1 doesn't show an error and client hangs after printing several "Making request ..." and "Response from ..." statements ending with a "Making request ...". Probably because it's waiting for that last request to complete.

This error only happens when a node forwards a query back to the node that it got the query from, this can be shown by setting n=1 in the make_request of the client in the above code.

Why does the task get cancelled when trying to read from reader?
Is there a way to allow the same recursive behaviour without causing an error?

Everything I could find regarding the "Pending Task Was Destroyed" error talked about how to properly create tasks so the garbage collector doesn't remove them but I'm not manually creating tasks. Is there something I have to do to save tasks on a server made using asyncio's start_server?

Thank you for your time and apologies for the wall of text.

Comment: reader.read() doesn't return a coroutine i guess

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly. Right now your code is not complete or reproducible and far from minimal. The practice of boiling the code down to the bare minimum needed to capture the essence of the problem not only motivates others to actually try and help you but more often than not gives you a deeper understanding to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @toing_toing Thank you for taking the time to comment. I checked the type returned by reader.read() and it is a coroutine. I rewrote the question so I hope it is more clear what is going on.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thank you for the advice. I rewrote the question (mainly the code) so it should be reproducible and hopefully sufficiently concise.