asyncio.Task is not garbage-collected after using del
Why is a task created with asyncio.create_task() in the below not garbage collected?
import asyncio
import gc

c = 0


async def run():
    global c
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            c += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(run())
    del task
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print(c)
        gc.collect()


asyncio.run(main())

Expected:
0
0
0
asyncio.CancelledError

Actual:
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
..
101
101
101
101
101
102
...


You cancel tasks with cancel, not with del.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938799/python-asyncio-create-task-really-need-to-keep-a-reference/76823668#76823668


task = asyncio.create_task(run())
del task


The local variable task was not the only reference to the task. One or more references to the task are still used by asyncio, so it is not garbage-collected.
You can see which objects hold references to the task by using gc.get_referrers:
task = asyncio.create_task(run())
print(gc.get_referrers(task))
del task

Output:
[<TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7f04ff32ece0>]

which is one of these.

asyncio.create_task isn't responsible for the reference - the event loop only holds weak references to tasks. Whether the task remains strongly reachable depends mostly on implementation details of what it awaits.

You can see an exploration of some of the relevant implementation details here, including why await asyncio.sleep(1) happens to preserve the task.
