Can asyncio.shield be correctly called with a coroutine argument?
asyncio.shield docs say:

If aw is a coroutine it is automatically scheduled as a Task.

and

Important: Save a reference to tasks passed to this function, to avoid a task disappearing mid-execution. The event loop only keeps weak references to tasks. A task that isn’t referenced elsewhere may get garbage collected at any time, even before it’s done.

Does the second clause also refer to tasks created internally when automatically wrapping coroutines? Does that further imply passing a coroutine to shield is never correct? Why does it support such automatic wrapping then?

@VPfB: Even if you saved a reference to the returned future, I think that future's reference to the inner task would be removed on cancellation.

Looking through CPython issue tracker discussion, I think calling asyncio.shield with a coroutine is actually just straight-up broken. People seem to be leaning toward having the event loop itself manage strong references to tasks to avoid all the awkward hassle of forcing users to do it. It's not clear why asyncio ever used weak references in the first place.

Using the idea from example #1 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823668/5378816 I could reproduce a disappearing task due to the returned future not saved or saved and cancelled. The user2357112 is right, it's broken.
